# R local repository synchronized with CRAN remote repository

Tags: r, cran

Is there any form of creating a R local repository on a Windows server which if I ask for an R package that isn't in local one, it ask for the remote CRAN one?

An scheme:

R desktop IDE on Windows -> R local repository in a Windows server ->  If there is not the package -> local R repository ask remote CRAN repository on the Internet.

I know that it's a strange scheme but I need to know if it's possible to implement.

Thank you so much

Comment: perhaps you could have your users set `repos=c(<your_local_repository>,<CRAN_mirror>)` ?

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the best option.